# How to substitute values in one row column based on values in another column?

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
#ID    DV    MDV#
  1     2     1
  2     3     0
  3     0     0
  4     .     0
```

I want the following:
Whenever DV column has a non-zero number, the MDV column should be 0 and vice-versa.
If DV has a zero value (or missing value), MDV should be 1 for that ID.

```
#ID    DV    MDV#
  1     2     0
  2     3     0
  3     0     1
  4     .     1
```

How do I code this?

Comment: Does the DV column really have a `.` in it?

Comment: Yes, it has '.' or '0'

Comment: Is it safe to assign `NA` to values that are `.`?

Comment: It is safe to assign '0' for '.'

Comment: I refuse to beleive that you did a minimal effort of finding an answer yourself and wasn't successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ifelse` might do the trick for you here.

Read your data:

```
> d <- read.table(h=T, text = "ID    DV    MDV
   1     2     1
   2     3     0
   3     0     0
   4     .     0", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Since `"." > 0` is `FALSE`, we can  reset the `MDV` column according to your specifications of the `DV` column as follows:

```
> d$MDV <- ifelse(d$DV > 0, 0, 1)
> d
#   ID DV MDV
# 1  1  2   0
# 2  2  3   0
# 3  3  0   1
# 4  4  .   1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a [`data.frame`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/data.frame.html) `f`, then you can do

```
f$MDV[f$DV > 0] <- 0
```

to set `MDV` to zero whenever `DV` is positive.